Drawer Menu Freezes in React Native App for Some Android Users
I'm encountering an issue with the drawer menu in my React Native app. Some users with Android devices report that the menu gets stuck and they can't navigate. I've implemented the menu using the @react-navigation/drawer library. Below is the relevant code for my navigation setup:
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function NavegationDrawerApp() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
      initialRouteName="Portada"
      screenOptions={{
        drawerActiveBackgroundColor: '#eb4947',
        drawerActiveTintColor: '#fff',
        drawerInactiveTintColor: '#000',
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        drawerLabelStyle: {
          marginLeft: -10,
          fontSize: 15,
        },
        headerTitle: () => (
          <Image
            source={require('./assets/img/logo.jpg')}
            style={{ width: 200, height: 45, resizeMode: 'contain', borderRadius: 10 }}
          />
        ),
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f23c38',
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Portada"
        component={Main}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({ color }) => <Ionicons name="trending-up" size={22} color={color} />,
          menu: true,
        }}
      />
      {/* Other Drawer.Screen components */}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

return (
  <>
    {!mantenimiento ? (
      storage ? (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="NavegationDrawerApp"
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: true,
              headerTitleAlign: "center",
              headerTitleStyle: { fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold" },
              headerStyle: { borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: "black" },
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen
              name="-"
              component={NavegationDrawerApp}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
            {/* Other Stack.Screen components */}
          </Stack.Navigator>
          <StatusBar style="light" />
        </NavigationContainer>
      ) : null
    ) : null}
  </>
);

Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "^49.0.9",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.17",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-progress-steps": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.15"
  },
  "private": true
}

I have attached a screenshot showing the issue Bug screenshot
Has anyone experienced similar issues or have suggestions on how to resolve this?
Thank you in advance!
Testing on different Android devices and emulators.
Reviewing the code for potential issues.
